# What happened to Aeka during the Nekoko and Mizuki stories?

Tags: yume-miru-kusuri

In the Aeka story, we see that Aeka is stuck in an incredibly bleak situation where she's being bullied at school by Kyouka Nanjou. She gets out of this situation by the end of her story with the protagonist's help, but it's rough going.

[image: aeka's ending]

After the Aeka story, I became obsessed and raced through the Mizuki and Nekoko stories in three days, so maybe I missed the finer points. Was it ever mentioned what happened to Aeka in these stories? Was she still able to escape from her situation without Kouhei's help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had forgotten that I took notes as I was playing the game. I shoved them off in a corner of my Dropbox and forgot about them, but they contained the answer to this question.

In both the Mizuki and Nekoko stories, Aeka attempts to commit suicide by jumping off the roof. She survives, but is hospitalized. She leaves behind a note accusing her tormentor, Kyouka Nanjou, which seems to lead to Nanjou's expulsion.

[image: Aeka on the edge of the roof]

In the Mizuki story, after Mizuki leaves school, Kouhei becomes the student council president. Because of what he saw happening to Aeka while they were classmates, he makes bullying his signature issue and tries to end the culture of silence where bystanders protect the bullies for fear of being targeted.

[image: Mizuki final shot]

As far as I can tell from my notes, the Nekoko story says nothing further about Aeka's fate.

[image: Nekoko chowing down]

In the bad ending, where you don't complete anyone's story, the narration states that Aeka just disappeared all of a sudden from school. Interestingly, you can get this bad ending even after Aeka has already attempted suicide and jumped off the roof. So she attempted suicide, was hospitalized, and then just disappeared all of a sudden from school.